# Headers in Google Script not Showing up Properly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to run this script that brings in Information from AD into a spreadsheet. But i also want to add in headers in the first row, however when I run this script it does freeze the first row, but instead of adding the header names, it just freezes the first persons name, email, phone, email, etc.. Is there a way to specify the main function to output starting from Row 2? or is there a better way to format this so the headers come in properly?

```
function writeToSpreadsheet(){
    var values = [];
    var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain:'domain.com'}).users; 
    for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
      values.push([users[i].name.fullName, getExternalID(users[i].externalIds || []), getPhones(users[i].phones || []),getDeviceName(users[i].organizations || []) ]);
      createHeaders();
    }

  
    var spreadsheetUrl = 'docs.googlesheet.com';
      SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
   
  }  
      
  
  function getExternalID(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(ExternalIDsObj) {
      return ExternalIDsObj.value;
    }).join(', ') + ('@email.com'); 
  }
          
  function getPhones(phones) { 
    return phones
      .map(phone => {
        const value = phone.value
        const type = phone.type.replace('_', ' ')
        return `${value} (${type})`
      })
      .join('\n');           
  }                                      
  
  function getDeviceName(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(OrganizationsObj) {
      return OrganizationsObj.costCenter;
    }).join(', ') ; //Cost Center = Device
  }
  
  
 function createHeaders() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.googlesheet.com');
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  
    // Freezes  first row
    sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    // header values
    var values = [
      ["NAME", "EMAIL", "PHONE NUMBER", "DEVICE"]
    ];
  
    // Set the range of cells
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:D1");
  
    // Call the setValues method on range and pass in our values
    range.setValues(values);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify the main function to output starting from
> Row 2

In `writeToSpreadsheet()`:

**Change:**

```
SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

**to:**

```
SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

Also there is absolutely no reason to execute `createHeaders` multiple times in the `for` loop since you only need to set and freeze the headers once.

---

**Full code of `writeToSpreadsheet`:**

```
function writeToSpreadsheet(){
    var values = [];
    var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain:'domain.com'}).users; 
    for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
      values.push([users[i].name.fullName, getExternalID(users[i].externalIds || []), getPhones(users[i].phones || []),getDeviceName(users[i].organizations || []) ]);          
    }    
    createHeaders(); // modified position
    var spreadsheetUrl = 'docs.googlesheet.com';
    SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values); // modified code    
  }
```